# Android HttpURLConnection NumberFormatException

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, numberformatexception

So Google Music does not have an official api, but there are unofficial ones floating around. Because it's unofficial we have to use ClientLogin rather than OAuth and I'm having problems with the following

URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

I get a NumberFormatException way down deep. Any ideas what's going on?

Here's the stack trace

```
Integer.parseInt(String, int) line: not available   
Integer.<init>(String) line: not available  
InetAddressCachePolicy.<clinit>() line: not available   
InetAddress$Cache.getPolicy() line: not available   
InetAddress$Cache.put(String, Object) line: not available   
InetAddress.cacheInitIfNeeded() line: not available 
InetAddress.cacheAddress(String, Object, boolean) line: not available   
InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(String, InetAddress) line: not available  
InetAddress.getLocalHost() line: not available  
SeedGenerator$1.run() line: not available   
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>) line: not available [native method]  
SeedGenerator.getSystemEntropy() line: not available    
SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>() line: not available    
SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(byte[]) line: not available    
SecureRandom.nextBytes(byte[]) line: not available  
SecureRandom.next(int) line: not available  
SecureRandom(Random).nextInt() line: not available  
DefaultSSLContextImpl(SSLContextImpl).engineInit(KeyManager[], TrustManager[], SecureRandom) line: not available    
DefaultSSLContextImpl.<init>() line: not available  
NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Constructor, Object[]) line: not available [native method]   
NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: not available 
DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: not available 
Constructor<T>.newInstance(Object...) line: not available   
Class<T>.newInstance0() line: not available 
Class<T>.newInstance() line: not available  
Provider$Service.newInstance(Object) line: not available    
GetInstance.getInstance(Provider$Service, Class) line: not available    
GetInstance.getInstance(String, Class, String) line: not available  
SSLContext.getInstance(String) line: not available  
SSLContext.getDefault() line: not available 
SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() line: not available   
HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory() line: not available 
HttpsURLConnectionImpl(HttpsURLConnection).<init>(URL) line: not available  
HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(URL, Proxy, Handler) line: not available  
Handler.openConnection(URL, Proxy) line: not available  
Handler.openConnection(URL) line: not available 
URL.openConnection() line: not available
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace or logcat?

Comment: I have a NumberFormatException breakpoint in Eclipse. Never though to just remove it - duh..